# Applying Solver to multiple

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm new to VBA, trying to apply Solver to multiple cells.
But I get an error: Sub or Function not defined.

Here is the code:

```
  Sub SolverRepeat()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 4 To 8763
    SolverReset
        SolverOk SetCell:="$BQ$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$BI$" & i, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you in the same excel that you run the sub? Or how do you run the macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have not added the reference to your VBA project.

**To do this**: 
In the Visual Basic Editor, with a module active, click `References` on the `Tools` menu, and then select `Solver` under `Available References`. If `Solver` does not appear under `Available References`, click `Browse`, and then open `Solver.xlam` in the `\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER subfolder`.

**Source**: [Using the Solver VBA Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196600.aspx)